# How to save Multiple Key Values using react-native-keychain?

Tags: react-native, react-native-keychain

I have multiple `key, value` and I dont know how can I store multiple `key, value` in different places.

Is there an alternative way for the following code using `react-native-keychain` package **??**

```js
await AsyncStorage.setItem('pincode',  '12345');
await AsyncStorage.setItem('userid',  '@user8383928');
await AsyncStorage.setItem('contacts',  JSON.stringify(contacts_array_of_object));
```

Every above `key, value saving` may called in different functions and in a different time.

Problem is in `react-native-keychain` there is only two property `username, password`:

```js
async () => {
  const username = 'zuck';
  const password = 'poniesRgr8';

  // Store the credentials
  await Keychain.setGenericPassword(username, password);

  try {
    // Retrieve the credentials
    const credentials = await Keychain.getGenericPassword();
    if (credentials) {
      console.log('Credentials successfully loaded for user ' + credentials.username);
    } else {
      console.log('No credentials stored');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Keychain couldn\'t be accessed!', error);
  }
  await Keychain.resetGenericPassword();
}
```

Comment: Does anyone know the solution for this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75081431/get-the-value-of-a-specified-field-from-a-keychain-with-multiple-key-value-pairs
Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

**1) setInternetCredentials**

`setInternetCredentials(server, username, password)` accepts server as first parameter. Server can be any string.

```js
await setInternetCredentials('pincode', 'pincode', '123456');
await setInternetCredentials('contacts', 'contacts', JSON.stringify(contacts_array_of_object));
```

You can then get it from keychain using

```js
await getInternetCredentials('pincode');
```

**2) setGenericPassword with service value**

`setGenericPassword(username, password, [{ accessControl, accessible, accessGroup, service, securityLevel }])` You have to specify service value, which is the name used for storing secret in internal storage

```js
await setGenericPassword('pincode', '123456', [{ service = 'pincode' }]);
```

**3) JSON.strigify with setGenericPassword**

Every time you would want to write something you would read keystore first and use object spread to store it back together with a new value.

Comment: In the latest version `Options` type for `setGenericPassword` is an object, so invocation would be `await setGenericPassword('pincode', '123456', { service: 'pincode' });`

Answer (score 3):

put them all in one object and then save it as `JSON.stringify({...})`

Comment: But there we need to save in different time